# Android list view wrap content until a certain size based on footer size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, height

I am working on an android application.

In an XML Layout I need to do the following:

I have a list view at the top (listViewProducts) , and another Relative view under it (receiptSection).

The list view should take as much space as it has items. And the rest is taken by the receiptSection.

So for example if I have 2 items in the listViewProducts:

[image: first image]

The list view is as big as the 2 items and the rest is taken by the receiptView.

If I add another item, the list view now take more space and push the receiptView lower:

[image]

However if I add a lot more items, I want the list view height to stop growing to leave a minimum height for the receiptView that cannot go smaller:

[image]

As you see in the picture, the receiptVIew has a minimum height of 50dp. once the receipt view get to that height, it should stop shrinking and now the list view has a fixed size based on the remaining of the space. The rest will be scrollable.

**What I have tried**

I created a list view. I have `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.

This will make it grow with its content and its at the top of the view

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewProducts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

THen I created a RelativeLayout that will hold the checkout_receipt_view that is in a seperate xml layout file.

For this view I have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_below="@id/listViewProducts"` that will make it go under the list view and align with the bottom of the view.

I also used `android:minHeight="50d"` in order to set the minimum height of the receiptSection.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/receiptSection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/listViewProducts"
    android:minHeight="50dp" >
    <include layout="@layout/checkout_receipt_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The listViewProducts is growing with the items, and the receiptView is taking the remaining space correctly.

**The problem**
however the minimum height did not work. The list view keeps on growing infinitely and the receiptSection will be pushed out of the view.

Is there a way I can make the listView stop growing when the receiptView reaches 50dp?

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think your best bet is to do this by making a custom view that extends `ListView` and overrides `onMeasure`.

```
public class CustomView extends ListView {

    @Override
    int maxHeight = 0;
    View parentView = (RelativeLayout) (or whatever) getParent();
    if (parentView != null){
        maxHeight = parentView.getHeight() - 50;
    }
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(maxHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try swapping the 'layout_below'.

What you are actually saying is the following: please put my relativelayout BELOW the listview. If you want your listview to respect the height of the relativelayout, you'll have to say in the listview:

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewProducts"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/receiptSection"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

And your relativelayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/receiptSection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:minHeight="50dp" >
    <include layout="@layout/checkout_receipt_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The "footer" section just takes up the whole screen because its height is set to match_parent. If you set it to wrap_content, it stays all the way at the bottom of the screen even if the list view only has 1 item, which is the problem we are trying to solve.